# Angular2 custom directive mousewheel is not working in IE 11.

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have written a directive for mousewheel.Which is working fine with chrome and firefox,But not working in IE.I have a dropdown and when I am scrolling inside dropdown then the entire page get scroll.I have written a directive but it work fine in chrome and firefox,but not in IE.I am followinf the link below.

```
[enter link description here][1] 




  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/dejs2Fo2YjrOK9EiJJve?p=preview
```

mousewheel.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, ElementRef,Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    //selector: '[scroller]',
    selector: '[scroller]',
})
export class ScrollerDirective {
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        renderer.listen(elRef.nativeElement, 'wheel', (e:any) => {
            let el = elRef.nativeElement;
            let conditions = ((el.scrollTop +  el.offsetHeight >  el.scrollHeight)) && e.deltaY > 0 || el.scrollTop === 0 && e.deltaY < 0;
            if (conditions) {
                e = e || window.event;
                if (e.preventDefault)
                    e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false; 
            } 
        })

    }

}
```

html

```
<ul scroller class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown addscroll" aria-labelledby="name2">
                            <li *ngFor="let errorcode of tabItems">
                                <a (click)="filterCode(errorcode?.clientCode, 'clintcode')" class="dropdown-item">{{ errorcode?.clientCode}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: It seems like you are using older angular version, try angular 2.X(latest) which might solve your issue.. Also add `es6-shim.js` on index page

Comment: It is woking well on my local but not working on production.